# Hudson build ignores .properties path

Tags: maven, hudson

I`m trying to build a maven project in Hudson and here I set the path for the .properties files. Yet it seems to get them from somewhere else (it definitely gets them because it connects to the db and runs some queries) because I set this to a invalid path on purpose.

There is no error and everything runs OK.

I need to add another variable to the .properties file and it seems to ignore it. Is there a temp/cache folder it uses?

**Goals and options:** clean process-resources "-Dproperties=/data/ic/test/aradd" -Denv=test site clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application uses a business and a batch component verify the properties for the business component. Be careful for the declared folder for your business component properties.